# Purging oracle statpack data does effect to the data?

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, oracle11g, database-administration

We have a production Oracle 11g SE1 database in an AWS RDS instance. Seems like the Oracle statpack user is using huge storage space from the total storage. I want to purge some statpack snapshots to free some space. Has purging those snapshots an effect to the data of the database? Or is there any other side effects?